# How to get a three-dimensional histogram from two-dimensional data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have two data lists:

```
x=[2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]
y=[700, 560, 450, 500, 570]
```

I needed to build a regular histogram (it was not difficult). But I also need a three-dimensional diagram, as in the figure [image: figure]. I tried various options (for example, bar3d), but it turns out not that. Help, please.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x= [float(i) for i in input('Input x ').split()]
y= [float(i) for i in input('Input y ').split()]

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(4,4))
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+xedges[1:], yedges[:-1]+yedges[1:])

xpos = xpos.flatten()/2.
ypos = ypos.flatten()/2.
zpos = np.ones_like (xpos)

dx = xedges [1] - xedges [0]
dy = yedges [1] - yedges [0]
dz = hist.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos,zpos , dx, 1, dz, color='b')
plt.xlabel ("X")
plt.ylabel ("Y")

plt.show()
```

Comment: what is three dimensional here? I see two dimensions, year and some value on the y-axis

Comment: There are only two dimensions in your histogram. It perhaps renders 3d bars. But the data is still 2d.

Comment: I understand that the data is two-dimensional, but it is necessary to obtain such a voluminous histogram. Maybe there are other options? But I did not find.

Comment: Why does it *have* to be 3D? Is this for homework? If anything, adding depth makes this *harder* to read than the regular 2D version.

Comment: Yes, this is homework; you need to build two histograms: regular and three-dimensional (from the same data).

Answer (score 1):

add this line to the first line of your code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

**Updated**
Hope this will help you.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x=[2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]
z=[700, 560, 450, 500, 570]
ax.bar3d(x, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I have it there, but it’s not used anywhere.

Comment: Thank you) i don't known how else to do this(